# Rosjava + Actionlib

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does rosjava + ROS Hydro support actionlib? I am having trouble finding examples.

Thanks!

Piyush

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73441/rosjava-+-actionlib/) by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2871 on 2013-08-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kirk](https://answers.ros.org/users/13101/kirk/) on 2014-03-10**:
I would like to know this as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It does not. https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_core/issues/152

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0